# Java converting collections

Tags: java, collections

Can someone explain this in detail-

```
List<Character> abc= new LinkedList<>();
```

For what reason we do this, please tell the internal working as much as possible

Comment: For what reason we do what? Coding? Creating lists?

Comment: Refer https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html

Comment: You're asking a broad question to which there are several resources online explaining what `Collections` and `Lists` are, refer to the [SO Documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/2989/lists/10149/creating-a-list#t=201608241043181580476) at the very least.

Comment: This question is too broad and off-topic IMHO. Too many reasonable answers and no way to know which is the one the OP needs. pradeep, please use your favourite search engine to find more information, then come back with a clearer and more specific question. Then we’ll be here to help.

Comment: I  mean what is difference when we use the below
List<character> abc = new LinkedList();
LinkedList<character> abc=new LinkedList();

Answer (score 0):

Basically, this allows you to look at variable with wider view, i.e. you want to work with a List but as in most cases it doesn't really matter what kind of List is it.

you could do something like this:

```
if(someIdentifier)
{
    return new ArrayList<String>()
} else
    return new LinkedList<String>()
}
```

Choosing between them might be related to the data type but irrelevant to the program itself.

For the internal usage this is the basic concept of OOP and you can find great information about it online.